# QML DoubleValidator separator

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquickcontrols2

I have a default `QLocale` set in `main.cpp`:

```
QLocale::setDefault(QLocale::c());
```

How can I also set `QLocale::RejectGroupSeparator` as default?

Alternatively: can I somehow set `RejectGroupSeparator` inside my `DoubleValidator` from `file.qlm`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not possible from QML, but in C++ you can do:

```
QLocale locale = QLocale::c();
locale.setNumberOptions(QLocale::RejectGroupSeparator);
QLocale::setDefault(locale);
```